# Type-hinting return value/functions in PHP

Tags: php, strong-typing, type-hinting, weak-typing

I did some research and came over this RFC which discusses type hinting for functions in PHP:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/returntypehint2

For example

```
public string getName()
{
    return 'martinmine';
}
```

Would be valid PHP code. Returning for example an array would yield an error in this case. Does anyone know the status on the RFC or if it got removed/added? I cannot seem to be able to make this function above work. I am using PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: It hasn't been implemented, and that RFC is a year old; and as far as I'm aware there is no active/current plans/voting to implement this.

Comment: @zerkms I would have written it in C# if I was able to.

Comment: I don't understand why are you recommending other language immediately. Question doesnt mention that. In that case we could all abandon php and code in C# or python or whatever. That's not the issue here.

About type hinting now - afaics it hasnt been introducted but look comments - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Return value typehinting has not been added - neither in PHP 5.5, not the upcoming PHP 5.6. There is currently no active discussion in that direction (it's a rather spiky topic ;)

Comment: [Hack](http://hacklang.org/) adds such typehinting

Answer (score 2):

Type hinting for return types are postponed to **PHP 7** (as of [this article](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types)), but the syntax is different than of the old purpose one:

```
function foo(): array {
    return [];
}
```

But it is already available in PHP 5 for parameters of type class of a method or function(as of [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)):

```
public function test_array(array $input_array) {
    print_r($input_array);
}
```